# Will the newest BSAFE crypto library handle a RSA-8192 key and a SHA-512 Hash?

Tags: cryptography, rsa, sha

I am currently using the BSAFE v6.0 cryptographic library for decryption and verification of digital signatures.  Security parameters are a RSA-4096 key and a SHA-256 hash.

Our customer is wanting to increase security parameters to a RSA-8192 key and a SHA-512 hash.  The BSAFE v6.0 library will not handle this.

It has come to my attention that a newer version of the BSAFE library is available (released in 2020).  Does anyone know if that version will handle a RSA-8192 key and a SHA-512 hash?

Thanks

Comment: there are many BSAFE libraries, Crypto C ME, SSL-J, etc. Which library are you referring to, and perhaps include a link to this new version.

Comment: Crypto-C ME.  Here is a link to the latest version: https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000181234/dell-bsafe-crypto-c-micro-edition-4-1-5-and-micro-edition-suite-4-6-release-advisory